# How do i search local maven repo for a package

Tags: java, maven

I have a package I need to use in my application and i want to search the (at least local) repo for g:a:v for any "dependency" that contians a package, say com.whatever.some.package can i do this via `mvn` ??? I saw dependency:get in doc but that's to search by g:a:v I want to search FOR gav(s) BY package name.

Obviously I can do it through shell: for jar in *.jar; do jar -tvf $jar | grep com.my.package && echo $jar; done

But that's a fairly hacky way to get what i want, I suppose the java fairies have come up with something better?

Comment: No. A good ide can do it for you.

Comment: Too bad. IDE windows are slow and i just need the gav for the package. Cml console is right there... Why I have to drive to the store to check if item is on the shelf, when I can call and ask?

Comment: Worth mentioning, though not what you're looking for, that IntelliJ provides a way to search dependencies: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#generate_maven_dependency

Comment: @niken broken analogy. Maven does not support this.  Sites exist where you can do these searches for public packages.

Comment: There's also: mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=g:a:v -o -DremoteRepositories=file://your/repo/path (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html)

Comment: @niken when you get more experienced with maven, you will learn what “opinionated software” means in the real world, and what difference a good IDE makes.

Comment: I think I had about as much experience with maven as i need , having to learn where to poke, press and rub an IDE on top of that is frustration i would prefer to avoid if possible

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any way to do this locally. But you can:

- Go to https://search.maven.org/
- Use `fc:` and then the full class name

Comment: This site is somewhat handy, but would be nice if i could do via command line form `mvn` itself, as this will search the entire maven repo, while my question pertains more to wth is going on in my local/internal setup. Also it's a pain to navigate search results. For a simple query of com.google.inject.internal i get 9700+ results, at 20 items per page it will take 9700/20/2 page views/loads/requests to find what i am looking for. How helpful? (sarcasm)

Comment: Your local repository is just a cache. Why is it so important which artifacts lie there? If you want a "local" search, you can set up a Nexus or Artifactory  server and then use its Web UI or REST service to search it.

Comment: You ever worked in an org behind a firewall? Yes it should be just a cache, but this theory does not hold up in practice and your local ~/.m2 becomes not just a cache but a delicate collection of past build artifacts, containing legacy project dependencies that are poorly managed... To the point where you even create backups of it on network storage.

Comment: In a company behind a firewall I would strongly recommend to run a Nexus or Artifactory server. This collects the artifacts you have build, caches the artifacts from MavenCentral and elsewhere and allows you to upload legacy artifacts. It is much better than trying to maintain a local repository.

Comment: You are getting off topic. I wasn't asking about maintaining a repo, which in itself is a good idea. I was asking about how to simplify looking for java PACKAGES in a maven repo in settings.xml (or my local one, in this instance). I should be able to do it via `mvn` from cml? (IMO)

Comment: I seriously doubt that Maven supports searching in the local repository, so I tried to describe how people usually solve the problem inside company networks.

Comment: Unfortunately searching maven.org is not helpful if one needs to search for private artifacts in a private repo. In that case one would need a way to search their cache, as the OP asked, or a way to search a remote maven repo through the mvn command line.

Comment: @Fopedush For a private repo, you can use the UI or the REST API of that repo. E.g. Artifactory has search in UI and a REST API. Nexus as well.